# Cisco Packet Tracer: Configure Switch to Boot Using Specified Image

Tags: networking, flash

I'm doing one of the Cisco Packet Tracer activities for my class and I'm having a problem on one particular point:

> **Step 1**. View current files stored in flash.
>
> On S1, enter the command show flash. You should see the following
>   files listed: S1#show flash Directory of flash:/
>
> ```
> 1  -rw-     4414921            c2960-lanbase-mz.122-25.FX.bin
> 3  -rw-     4670455            c2960-lanbase-mz.122-25.SEE1.bin
> 2  -rw-         616            vlan.dat
> ```
>
> 32514048 bytes total (23428056 bytes free)
>
> **Step 2**. Configure S1 to
>   boot using the second image listed.
>
> Make sure your command includes the file system, which is flash. Note:
>   Packet Tracer does not show this command in the running configuration.
>   In addition, if you reload the switch, Packet Tracer does not load the
>   image you specified.

I'm looking at [Cisco's documentation](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios/12_2/configfun/command/reference/ffun_r/frf010.html) and from what I can see the commands should be:

```
S1>conf t
S1#boot flash c2960-lanbase-mz.122-25.SEE1.bin
```

However the CLI indicates invalid input at the "f" in flash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contrary to what the online documentation clearly says (is it outdated?) the command in this particular case is:

```
boot system flash:c2960-lanbase-mz.122-25.SEE1.bin
```

Hope this helps anyone else running into this issue (Google shows I wasn't the only one having this issue on this lab and I didn't see the answer posted anywhere else!)

Answer (score -1):

The command that packet tracer actually accepts is this:

```
S1(config)#boot system flash:/c2960-lanbase-mz.122-25.SEE1.bin
```

Comment: You can save the config : copy run start save to default and then reboot and it will load from the flash image you inserted.